# Confused about using relative and absolute path in Python

Tags: python, python-import, relative-path

I have a script called "test.py" and refers to a config file called "cfg.yaml". These two reside in the same directory called "test/scripts".

```
test/scripts/test.py
test/script/cfg.yaml
```

Now I am writing a bash script inside "test/data1/data2" called task.sh

From inside of task.sh, I want to make a call to the python script

test.sh contents are as below:

```
#!/bin/sh

python ../../scripts/test.py
```

test.py opens and reads the cfg.yaml like open("cfg.yaml") but when the test.sh is called, it fails because "cfg.yaml" is NOT referred with relative path. How do I resolve this?

Comment: 1. you could run test.py from test/scripts, 2. inside test.py you could change the path to cfg file as '../../scripts/test.py' or 3. you could use absolute path for the cfg file. This happens because python interpreter is being called from test/data1/data2

Comment: Relative paths are relative to the current working directory, not relative to the location of the file being executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
#!/bin/sh

cd ../../scripts
python test.py
```

I assume in test.py you are referencing the yaml with a local path that expects the script to be running from the scripts directory  (not from `data1/data2`)

as an aside you can always `print os.getcwd()` to see what your working directory is while running the python script (or just `pwd` in bash)

Comment: I like your solution the best! Thanks Joran. I did not know that I could execute Python scripts directly from inside of a bash script.It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer to a file in terms of its relative location *to the script*, you can't just use a relative path for that, because the script may not be in the current working directory. In fact, in your case, it's guaranteed *not* to be in the current working directory.

The usual quick&dirty solution is to get the script path explicitly:

```
import os
import sys

scriptdir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
```

<sub>That [`sys.argv[0]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) is the full name of your script—which on most platforms means either an absolute path, or a relative path that's at least still valid at this point. If you're worried about those other platforms, you may want to look at [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html?highlight=__file__#__file__). Of course if you're running the script out of a zipfile or similar, neither one will be useful.</sub>

```
open(os.path.join(scriptdir, "cfg.yaml"))
```

(Or you can even forcibly `os.chdir(scriptdir)` if you want, but that can be a bad idea if you're, e.g., accepting pathnames from the user.)

The *right* solution is to write your script and data files to be *installed* (even if you don't actually install anything and run it out of the source tree), and then use `pkg_resources` to find the data files. That will also solve a whole lot of other problems for you—but it does require a bit more learning first. See the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/current.html) if you want to get started on that road, and [Package Data and Data Files](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distributing.html#package-data) as particular starting points.